# C# windows form, track user login

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three forms, signup ,login and after they have logged the dashboard will display their last edit on a text editor in C#. The project is an offline user login system, and not using any ASP.

I am thinking how to pass data after the user logs in in, so the form can retrieve and show data of that particular user. Everything is stored in a text file.

Comment: I don't understand what you have now, what you're trying to do, or what's stopping you from doing whatever it is you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, it will require sharing data between the Forms. That data can be a session ID, the Login Information stored in memory or even a class instance you hand around.

Sharing any form of data between Windows Forms is a tricky thing. Doing this in WPF is way easier. And ASP.Net actually has dedicated support for this (as it is way worse there with the page lifecycle). So the question you should be asking is:

"How do I share data between Forms?" Wich data you share from then on is a minor detail.